# Return a value from if there is match between 2 tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

First I'll describe scenario, I've 2 tables, 1st table with columns like Hsname, prod, ver & bundled (fill-up values using formulas) and 2nd table with columns like prod, ver and bundled. I've to fetch values from 2nd table bundled column to 1st table bundled column on exact match of prod & version in both tables. Below is the screenshot attached and formula used

```
=IF(AND(MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$14,0),MATCH(Sheet1!C2,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$14,0)),Sheet2!C2:C14,"No")
```

note: I'm using old version of excel where I'm unable to use dynamic array.

[image: table1]

[image: table2]

[image: Image 4]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little bit out of the old-fashioned formulae, so maybe someone can come up with something cleaner, but here are my two cents:

[image]

Formula in `D2`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(H$2:INDEX(H:H,SUMPRODUCT((F$2:F$14=B2)*(G$2:G$14=C2)*ROW(H$2:H$14)))<>""),H$2:H$15&"")
```

- `LOOKUP()` will, as it were, auto-CSE this formula for you, where;
- We concatenate each value in the lookup range with an empty string to prevent unwanted results (zeros);
- A boolean structure is used to find the row number;
- `INDEX()` is used to build a dynamic range of which `LOOKUP()` can find the last (and also 1st) value from our lookup range.

Note that this works because the topleft cell of an merged range holds its value. Also note that merged cells are Excel's worst nightmare.

Note that the lookup range is one cell past the range of column `F:G`, e.g.: `H$2:H$15`, for a purpose because it would throw an error instead of empty strings if the very last bundle is not a merged cell but a single cell on it's own.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you might be looking for,

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($I$2:$I$14),
ROW($I$2:$I$14)/($I$2:$I$14<>""),$I$2:$I$14),
MATCH(B2&C2,$G$2:$G$14&$H$2:$H$14,0)),"")
```

So let me explain a little bit on the above formula, how it works,

• First I have concatenated the **Product** & **Version** cells and used **MATCH** Function to find the position of each

```
MATCH(B2&C2,$G$2:$G$14&$H$2:$H$14,0)
```

• Next I have used a **LOOKUP** Function along with **ROW** Function to create an array of the bundles columns

```
LOOKUP(ROW($I$2:$I$14),ROW($I$2:$I$14)/($I$2:$I$14<>""),$I$2:$I$14)
```

[image: ARRAY_OF_BUNDLES]

• Lastly I am wrapping the all within an **INDEX** Function & **IFERROR** Function(To Ignore the errors)

```
=INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($I$2:$I$14),
ROW($I$2:$I$14)/($I$2:$I$14<>""),$I$2:$I$14),
MATCH(B2&C2,$G$2:$G$14&$H$2:$H$14,0))
```

Hence we get our desired output as expected!

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

### EDIT

### Using Helper Columns

With helper columns also it can be achieved. please refer the image below

• Formula used in Helper Column **J**

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($I$2:I2<>""),$I$2:I2)
```

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$14,MATCH(1,(B2=$G$2:$G$14)*(C2=$H$2:$H$14),0)),"")
```

Array formulas need to be entered using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

And Fill Down !

[image: HELPER]

### Edit

Without Helper same above Formula works, If you are not Excel 2021 Or O365 Users you need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LOOKUP(ROW($J$2:$J$14),
ROW($J$2:$J$14)/($J$2:$J$14<>""),$J$2:$J$14),
MATCH(1,(B2=$H$2:$H$14)*(C2=$I$2:$I$14),0)),"")
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Comment: Be extremely cautious about these concatenated values. I always advocate against it. What if `B2` = 'A1' and `C2` = '14' for table one.  It would easily return a false positive when it finds 'A11' and '4' under table two. They both equal 'A114'.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, absolutely agreed with you, sorry for the delay in response, my internet got disconnected. But however if there is no `A11` and `4` then this should be working without any issue.

Comment: Interesting point @JvdV. So maybe use an obscure delimiter with unlikely incidence? e.g., `B2 & "° K-pop is cool °" & C2`

Comment: @markfitzpatrick, either that or a boolean structure for exact matching.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, I wouldn't want to take that chance with a dataset. But yes, if that specific piece of data is not present your formula will work.

Comment: @JvdV Sir absolutely `BOOLEAN` is Cool, and yes i forgot to mention that you have done already that merged cells should not be used in any ways. `Merged Cells` are `Devils workshop` !!

Comment: @JvdV Sir, one more thing, I recently read somewhere that using `IFERROR` function just reduces the speed of `Excel` functionality is it `TRUE`,

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, to be honest I haven't heard about that, but I do know that every calculation is a calculation that will make things a little bit slower (though most likely negligable). Look at it this way: If you have a formula that would perform 10 steps, but after the 2nd step it would evaluate to an error; Excel would still try to finish the other 8 steps even though the final answer would be an error. A lot of processing for nothing. This is my take but obviously subjective to what I know/think.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, noted thank you so much again for the knowledge share!

Comment: @JvdV and Mayukh - I suppose it is a trade-off in any case. IFERROR is intended to reduce calc time and complexity: `IFERROR(*complex formula*,*alternate result*)` should take less time than the alternative `IF(ISERR(*complex formula*),*complex formula*,*alternate result*)`. In the latter, *complex formula* is processed twice when it does not error, otherwise once. Seems likely to be more wasteful. However, if we are using IFERROR as a way to force errors for filtering, then I can see that, yes, it's perhaps a slow way to do things.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick sir, hmm understood, very insightful !

Comment: the formula isn't working, return blank values @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @ROn Sir, could you show me a screenshot where it is not working, because I have also shared a screenshot with the query image you have posted,

Comment: @ROn Sir, its best to avoid merged cells, hence create a helper column and then use `INDEX` & `MATCH` Function

Comment: @ROn Sir, if you are ok with `Helper Columns`, then please refer the solution above, I have edited. However both formula works, there is no issue, only one issue in the last formula which @JvdV Sir has pointed out in the first comment of the thread, otherwise its good to go!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya sir thank you, I removed merged cells and added the data in all rows. I've attached error screenshot for reference. It appears that Match formula gives #value as error. Sorry I'm not aware of helper columns.

Comment: @ROn sir i have edited my query showing solution with helper column. If you wish,  you can follow that as well. See end of the last of column of 2nd table create one column and place the formula as I have shown `(LOOKUP FORMULA)` and then use the Index and Match function in cell D2 and fill down

Comment: @ROn Sir refer the image link, same formula without any error, I dont know why you are getting error values, https://imgur.com/L8ZGPKc

Comment: @ROn Sir, after entering the formula, you need to press `CTRL SHIFT ENTER` together

Comment: @ROn Sir, this is image showing with the second formula, https://imgur.com/cR6Akwv

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya sir thank you : CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER did work
previous and recent formula works good. Thank you once again & for your support.

Comment: @ROn Sir, thank you very much! Glad you have resolved the query!